# Saving Backbone model and collection to JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, save, backbone.js

I'm having problem saving Backbone.Model or Backbone.Collection objects to local storage.
The problem is that when it saves, only the attributes gets saved and I do not want that.
I'm actually using the backbone-localstorage thats provided in their sample TODO demo.

This is their save function

```
save: function() {          
    localStorage.setItem(this.name, JSON.stringify(this.data));
}
```

When I look at what JSON.stringify(this.data) returns, I see only the models or the collection's attributes gets sets. Is there a way to specify that I want to save the whole state the model and collection is in, not just the attributes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Override the Model.toJSON or Collection.toJSON to return the data you want serialized.

The default Model.toJSON just returns the attributes:

```
toJSON : function() {
  return _.clone(this.attributes);
}
```

the Collection's toJSON utilizes the Model's toJSON:

```
toJSON : function() {
  return this.map(function(model){ return model.toJSON(); });
}
```

Comment: But I'm actually calling JSON.stringify not model.toJSON() so shouldn't the whole model set stringified and not just the attributes? Unless JSON.stringify calls the model.toJSON()?

Comment: That's the way JSON.stringify works.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify  "If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value is a function, then the toJSON method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the toJSON method when called will be serialized."

Comment: One more question, Suppose I have a Model called SaveModel, in which that model gets saved in local storage and the SaveModel has attributes say NodeModel. So essentially I have a model within a model. When I save SaveModel, its attributes gets saved as well, so NodeModel gets saved as well. So when I go to retrieve NodeModel attributes from SaveModel, can I assume NodeModel will be of type NodeModel? That is, can I just assign say NodeModel n = SavedModel.nodeModel? Or do I have to reinitialize it like so, NodeModel n = new NodeModel(SavedModel.nodeModel)? I'm trying to achieve the former.