# Emitting a Backbone.js Model through Socket.io

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, socket.io

**BASIC QUESTION**
I am trying to send an object through socket.emit() but the object is not being fully sent. I may just be misunderstanding how to do this, but here's the example:

```
console.log(object)
```

RESULTS IN

```
{ length: 8,
  models:
   [ { attributes: [Object],
       _escapedAttributes: {},
       cid: 'c1',
       changed: {},
       _silent: {},
       _pending: {},
       _previousAttributes: [Object],
       lots: [Object],
       _changing: false,
       collection: [Circular],
       _callbacks: [Object] },
    ... ETC
```

While

```
socket.emit(e,object);
```

RESULTS IN :

```
{"name":"read:AllAuctions","args":
[[{"auctionId":"298"},{"auctionId":"381"},{"auctionId":"385"},
{"auctionId":"393"},{"auctionId":"394"},{"auctionId":"395"},
{"auctionId":"402"},{"auctionId":"800"}]]}
```

It arrives to the front-end in the latter format.

**WAY MORE DETAIL**
I've created a server that is attempting to update a client-side backbone model using socket.io. Some of it is using the ideas specified here:

http://developer.teradata.com/blog/jasonstrimpel/2011/11/backbone-js-and-socket-io

The difference is that I've created backbone models on the back end. My logic was to share the basic model files, and have the back-end deal with communicating with the persistance layer and keeping the "true" data source optimized, but then respond to requests to fetch those models/collections as well as automatically pushing updates.

Everything seems to be working except for however I'm supposed to transfer the model to the front-end. Do I need to extend/overwrite toJSON or another method that actually converts it for transport? If so, how do I do that? Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but I found the problem in another question:
[Saving Backbone model and collection to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753512/saving-backbone-model-and-collection-to-json-string)

Essentially, what I didn't realize was that toJSON() only returns the attributes of the model. My models contained a collection of other models, so I needed to overwrite toJSON().

Collections call the toJSON() of their child model. So, I ultimately needed to change the model's toJSON function to return the attributes AND the collection of models they contained.

Here's the example:

```
var Auction = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    auctionId : null
  },
  toJSON : function() {
    var returnObject = {};
    returnObject["auctionId"] = this.get("auctionId");
    returnObject["lots"] = this.lots;
    return returnObject;
  },
  initialize : function() {
    this.lots = new Lots;
  }
});
```

Please note in my example that rather than returning all attributes of the model, I'm just returning the attribute "auctionId." This to me seemed safer because another developer here might later add attributes that do not need to be transported. That being said, it's probably better practice to make an element of the returnObject contain all the attributes. This just made my re-building of the model on the client-side a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should only sent the data and recreate the object on the client-side.

Therefor you could try using Backbone Collection's [`toJSON`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-toJSON)

```js
socket.emit(e, object.toJSON());
```

Comment: I thought that might be the issue too, but it does the same thing. Is there a chance I need to overwrite the toJSON method for that collection in order to make sure it also returns the full body of each child model? I've tried that but I might have done it wrong because it returned the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turns out that the socket was already trying to encode it by using toJSON but my toJSON function was only returning the attributes of the models in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Before sending use JSON.stringify and deserialize on the other end with JSON.parse

Comment: I get the same problem. The complex object becomes just an array of name:value pairs for the one attribute on each model in the collection.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't realize that toJSON only returns an object ready for JSON stringification.