# How can I ensure that my Backbone forms return data that's formatted the same way as it came in?

Tags: json, backbone.js, marionette

In short:

When using Backbone and Underscore templates, what's the best way to ensure that the data in a form is formatted in the exact same way when POSTed to the server as it was when it was initially fetched?

Longer question:

I'm currently using Backbone’s `fetch()` to retrieve some data from the server as JSON. On `success` I'm taking that JSON and using the data in an Underscore template like so:

```
<div class="module-content">
    <form>
        <div class="customer-primary">
            <% if (ParentCompany) { %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">Parent Company</div>
                <div class="value">
                    <div class="current-value"><%= ParentCompany %></div>
                    <div class="editable-value"><input name="ParentCompany" value="<%= ParentCompany %>"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% } %>
            <% if (Title) { %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">Title</div>
                <div class="value">
                    <div class="current-value"><%= Title %></div>
                    <div class="editable-value"><input name="Title" value="<%= Title %>"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% } %>
            …
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The JSON has a number of children with multiple entries, like this:

```
{
   "UserID":"12345",
   "FirstName":"Brandon",
   "Ship": {
      "Address1":"33 One Two Ave",
      "Address2":"#23D",
      "Address3":"",
      "City":"New York",
      "State":"NY",
      "Country":"United States",
      "Zip":"10023"
   },
   "Phones": [
      {
         "Kind":"Tel",
         "Number":"512-123-4567"
      },
      {
         "Kind":"Fax",
         "Number":"512-123-4567"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I ensure that I build the form out in such a way that it returns an object that's formatted in the same way for easy DB updates?

Please let me know if you need more info!

Comment: Why do you mean "formatted the same way"?

Comment: I just mean that the serialized JSON object I send back on POST will be formatted in the same way as it was when it came in.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at some plugins that manage forms / databinding. http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/ https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "formatted the same way"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're trying to make sure the JSON data structure matches what the server expects when you're sending data. (And coincidentally, that it's in the same structure that you received from the server.)

What you want to do is override the model's toJSON function so your data is serialized as expected. Then, when it gets persisted by Backbone.sync, the proper data structure will be sent to the remote API.

Take a look at these:

- [Saving Backbone model and collection to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753512/saving-backbone-model-and-collection-to-json-string)
- [backbone.js: overwritting toJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958747/backbone-js-overwritting-tojson)

Comment: That's right. The tricky thing for me is that both the received and the sent JSON will have child objects that are 2–3 levels deep ("Phones" in my sample above). Not sure what to do in those instances.

Comment: I suspect I'd use array values for that scenario:

`<input type="text" name="Phones['<%= Phone.Kind %>']" value="<%= Phone.Number %>">`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is to validate your model. and make the fields that you need to be sent required, if you need all of them ,then validate your entire model.
This plugin is a good option for this task.
https://github.com/fantactuka/backbone-validator